# Improve loading dataframe into postgress db with python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

Today I started to learn postgress and I was tryng to do the same thing that I do to load dataframes into my Oracle db

So, for example I have a df that contains 70k of records and 10 columns. My code for this is the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine('postgresql://'+data['user']+':'+data['password']+'@'+data['host']+':'+data['port_db']+'/'+data['dbname'])

df.to_sql('first_posgress', conn)
```

This code is kinda the same I use for my Oracle tables but in this case it takes several time to accomplish the task. So I was wondering if there is a better way to do this or it is because in postgress in general is slower.

I found some examples on SO and google but mostly are focused on create the table, not insert a df.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use psycopg2 instead of SQLALchemy you can transform your df into a csv and then use cursor.copy_from() to copy the csv into the db.

```
import io

output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep=",")
output.seek(0)

#psycopg2.cursor:
cursor.copy_from(   
        output,
        target_table,  #'first_posgress'
        sep=",",
        columns=tuple(df.columns)
    )
con.commit() #psycopg2 conn
```

(I don't know if there is an similar function in SQLAlchemy, that is faster too)

Psycopg2 Cursor [Documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html)

This [blogpost](https://naysan.ca/2020/05/09/pandas-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2-bulk-insert-performance-benchmark/) contains more information!

Hopefully this is useful for you !